# ftrace leads to linux blocking and no response

Tags: ftrace

I am working on GPON ONT (Broadcom 68380(MIPS32), 256MB memory) Linux kernel 3.4.11rt, after type in echo function > current_tracer, the console no response.

```
ONT3@: cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
ONT3@: # echo 'rdpa*' > set_ftrace_filter
ONT3@: # echo 0 > tracing_on
ONT3@: # echo function > current_tracer <--- ONT stucked here
```

I run the above commands in Ubuntu16.04 everything is ok.

There is one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044214/ftrace-on-android-freeze-when-turn-on-function-trace-somebody-help-me) (Title is "Ftrace on android freeze when turn on function trace, somebody help me"), but I already filtered with 'rdpa*' and narrow down the filter even with one function, system still blocked, the Magic SysRequest Key also no response.

```
detail log:
ONT3@:/ # mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug
ONT3@:/ # cd sys/kernel/debug/
ONT3@:/sys/kernel/debug # ls
bdi      mips     tracing  usb
ONT3@:/sys/kernel/debug # ls -l
drwxr-xr-x   26 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 bdi
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 mips
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 tracing
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 usb
ONT3@:/sys/kernel/debug # cd tracing/
ONT3@:/sys/kernel/debug/tracing # ls -l
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 README
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 available_events
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 available_filter_functions
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 available_tracers
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 buffer_size_kb
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 buffer_total_size_kb
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 current_tracer
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 dyn_ftrace_total_info
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 enabled_functions
drwxr-xr-x   27 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 events
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 free_buffer
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 options
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 per_cpu
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 printk_formats
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 saved_cmdlines
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 set_event
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 set_ftrace_filter
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 set_ftrace_notrace
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 set_ftrace_pid
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 set_graph_function
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 trace
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 trace_clock
--w--w----    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 trace_marker
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 trace_options
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 trace_pipe
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 tracing_cpumask
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 tracing_enabled
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 tracing_on
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 tracing_thresh
ONT3@:/sys/kernel/debug/tracing # cat current_tracer
nop
ONT3@:/sys/kernel/debug/tracing # echo function > current_tracer
```

What should I do to fix this issue? Please share your comments.

Thank you so much.

Comment: There is a patch here (https://www.linux-mips.org/archives/linux-mips/2010-08/msg00143.html), but latest kernel is difference on this part.